# How to get pictures metadatas on windows phone?

Tags: metadata, windows-phone, latitude-longitude, image

I choose a picture with a PhotoChooserTask and I would like to get metadatas (longitute, latitude, device, ect) from this picture. How can I do that ?

My code:

```
    void photochoosertask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        im.Source = bmp;

        //get metadatas ?
    }
```

Comment: There are suggestions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722898/read-exif-data-from-image-on-wp

Comment: Already answered here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661825/windows-phone-7-picture-metadata

Answer (score 0):

If by chance you happen to be uploading the image to a service that has access to the full .NET Framework, you can also use the BitmapMetadata class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619225.aspx.